# RESTful API with Google API and OAuth2

Tags: google, oauth2, jwt, rest

As the title says, I want to create a RESTful API (stateless) that will access Google API endpoints. First I want to authenticate the user and then use that token provided by Google to access Google Calendar API.

This is the current flow of the app:

[image]

Is there any other way to achieve this since my Nodejs service is signing an already signed JWT token provided by Google (I need to track expiration times for both access tokens)?

I am doing this because I don't want to use Google's access token for my own endpoint authentication.

Comment: Why are you re-signing JWT of Google? That is already signed.

Comment: @defalt to protect my own API routes (I can verify using secret the identity of the sender)

Comment: Then your current design is fine. The lifespan of your signature should not exceed the expiry of the access token.